# Bluemix Push Notifications service returns error "502 Bad Gateway"

Tags: push-notification, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I'm successfully using the push notifications service provided by Bluemix, but a few days ago the push service became unavailable, at least for configuration purposes.

The only hint I've got is that my trial expired and had to enter my credit card, maybe that caused this problem.

**Here's the exception thrown:**

```
Exception thrown by application class 'com.ibm.mbaas.ui.BackendUtility.getJSONResponse:-1'
javax.servlet.ServletException: UIBACK108E: Got unsuccessful response from 'https://mccp.ng.bluemix.net/login/rolecheck?role=developers&space_guid=568581a0-9bbd-4fbf-9fb0-243c0d7febc3'. The response status was 502 Bad Gateway. The response body was: "502 Bad Gateway: Registered endpoint failed to handle the request. ".
at com.ibm.mbaas.ui.BackendUtility.getJSONResponse(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.mbaas.ui.BackendUtility.checkRole(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.mbaas.ui.security.UAACallBackServlet.doGet(Unknown Source)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1285)
at [internal classes]
```

Comment: Are you still experiencing this exception?

Comment: It seems to be working fine right now. So, should I assume it was indeed related to my credit card?

Answer (score 0):

There may be times when the service itself becomes temporarily unavailable and can cause errors like this. Our team is working around the clock when these outages occur so be sure to check the status page for announcements/status when you think something is wrong.

https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status

You can also check announcements on the developer works forum or post a question if the status pages are not reflecting your issues.